# dynamic number of chart.js charts on the same page

Tags: php, chart.js

I'm trying to place multiple graph.js generated graphs on the single page within of PHP-script. Since the number of graph may/will be varying, I don't know how I can avoid the issue with the `window.onload` function being loaded multiple times. Hence the other solutions here and on the web didn't worked for me. The only very last chart is getting content and all the previous canvases stay blank. Please point me into the right direction.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
    while ($payment = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {

        if($Year != $payment['Year']) {
            $Year = $payment['Year'];
    ?>
    <div style="font-weight:bold; text-align:left; padding-left:20px; <?php if ($Year > 0) { ?> margin-top:15px; <?php } ?> border-bottom:1px solid #CCC; border-top:1px solid #CCC; background-color:#EEE; color:#666">
    payments in the year <?php echo $payment['Year']; ?>
    </div>

    <!--  -->

        <div style="width: 40%">
             //generate an unique  canvas id
            <canvas id="<?php echo $payment['Year']; ?>"></canvas>
        </div>
        <script>
            var barChartData = {
                labels: ["l1test", "l2test", "l3test"],
                datasets: [{
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(44,129,54,0.9)",
                    data: [2, 23, 24]
                }]
            };
            window.onload = function () {
                var ctx = document.getElementById("<?php echo $payment['Year']; ?>").getContext("2d");
                window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: barChartData,
                    options: {
                        title: {
                            display: false,
                            text: "legend"
                        },
                        tooltips: {
                            mode: 'label'
                        },
                        responsive: true,
                        scales: {
                            xAxes: [{
                                stacked: true
                            }],
                            yAxes: [{
                                stacked: true
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                });
            };
        </script>
}//end of while loop here
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did included jQuery, changed `canvas id...` to `canvas class` and created a file `script.js` with following jQuery code where I call window.onload function for every class.

```
$(function($) {
    $('.chart').each(function (index, element) {
        var ctx = element.getContext('2d');
        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: barChartData,
            options: {
                title: {
                    display: false,
                    text: 'Bierkonsum'
                },
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'label'
                },
                responsive: true,
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        stacked: true
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: true
                    }]
                }
            }
        });

    });
});(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a unique ID, checking it's not been used, using that, like so:

```
$keys = array();
$from = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

while ($payment = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
    do {
        $key = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            $key .= substr($from, rand(0, strlen($from) -1), 1);
        }
    } while (in_array($key, $keys));
    $keys[] = $key;

    // use $key for the ID

}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's just a prototype to show what i want to do. I'm getting troubles with something different but ID's. The ID'S in the example code are unique.  The issue is within of my head and graphs.js `onload` function. That function overwrites all charts, but the last one.